# return the sample dimension of distribution `d`

Tags: python, julia, distribution

I want to write a `python` code of multivariate distribution but when I want for example to return the sample dimension of distribution `d` i don't know if i am doing it right or not, I've found a `julia` example of what i want to do see the code bellow: 
I'm still feeling that i'm missing something that i don't know what it is in the python version.

and the `python` code that I have tried to give me the same thing as the `julia`code is:

```
python
def length(d, x):

    d= scipy.stats._multivariate

    len(x) == len(d) or print("dimension mismatch")

    length(d, x)
```

```
julia

function rand!(d::MultivariateDistribution, x::AbstractVector)
    length(x) == length(d) ||
        throw(DimensionMismatch("Output size inconsistent with sample length."))
    _rand!(d, x)
end
```

Comment: You might have better luck with the docs for the [multivariate_normal](http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) function in scipy, from what I can tell, the `_multivariate` is the overall module that contains various other classes for multivariate functions as outlined [here](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/scipy-1.0.0rc2/autoapi/stats/_multivariate/index.html)

Comment: yes i know that the `_multivariate`is the overall module but i want to try to do here is like create a multivariate sampler not a multinomial or normal

Comment: I'm afraid I am having trouble understanding what you're trying to do, exactly. It sounds like you're trying to draw samples from the abstract _concept_ of an unbounded multivariate distribution. Again, apologies for my confusion, but that sounds to my ear like trying to determine the gas mileage of a "vehicle" without specifying car or truck or airplane etc. From what I can tell, the julia code you posted also includes abstract functionality for for the base class, which requires you to define the distribution before you can actually draw random samples from it

Comment: The Julia code is doing essentially nothing and is itself not a helpful template for reimplementing the code in Python — it's just adding an argument check before calling an unsafe internal function (`_rand!`) that actually does the work.

Comment: i agree with you at this point what about if i want  a discret multivariational distribution or we can call it multinomial, in this case i should change `_multivariate`by `multinomial`but what else am i missing there still feeling like i'm still missing something between the two codes

Comment: @MattB. then how can i write this function because i spent the whole night without knowing how am i going to do, i don't know if there is a special function in pythin like `rand!`

Comment: What _kind_ of multivariate distribution do you want to implement?  The term "multivariate distribution" simply means that each sample is a vector — but it doesn't describe _how_ you generate each sample.  Really, though, you don't want to implement this yourself.  Just use Julia (or scipy).

Comment: @MattB. i want to use the `multinomial`distribution`in fact i want to write this function in python as a small part of the struggles that i am facing here because in `julia`you can do that by only typing `Base.Length(d::name_of_the_structure)=length(d.x)`and the julia code above is the source of this line .

Comment: Then use [`Distributions.Multinomial`](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/latest/multivariate/#Distributions.Multinomial) or  [`scipy.stats.multinomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multinomial.html)?